# Is there a way to have an instance of UIView inherit from UIControl programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

In many iOS books and tutorials they demonstrate how in interface builder you can basically turn a UIView into a UIControl and have it inherit new higher level functionality to respond to clicks and behave like button for example. This is done simply by changing the class type in interface builder of a selected UIView.

This is often done to dismiss the keyboard when someone touches on the "background" or main view of a given view controller.  Once a UIView's class is changed to a UIControl you just assign connect a new IBAction for when a TouchUpInside event occurs for example.

Now I understand this concept but it seams like a weird Xcode hack. The reason is, I don't see how I could accomplish the same thing programatically. Let me explain:  If I create an instance of a UIView in code and I want it to behave like a UIControl how would I tell this UIView instance that I want it to inherit from UIControl.  Now keep in mind I don't actually want to subclass UIControl because that would be jumping through more hoops and I don't think that is what Interface Builder is doing when you change that class type, or is it?  Also, keep in mind UIControl is meant to be an abstract class and not to be used directly otherwise I would probably just do that.

Ultimately my question is, is there an equivalent way to accomplish the same thing in pure code and have a UIView become a UIControl such that I can assign the higher level events to it?

I hope this makes sense, if not I can elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIControl` inherits from `UIView`, so if you wanted to do this programmatically, you would just create an instance of `UIControl` instead. So if you were creating a view controller's view programmatically, for instance, you could do something like:

```
- (void)loadView
{
  CGRect viewSize = /* some appropriate default size */
  UIControl* myControlView = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:viewSize];
  // configure your control (e.g., set events, etc)
  [self setView:myControlView];
  [myControlView release]; // omit this line if using ARC
}
```

Comment: I see your point, but like I said according to Apple's documentation they say and I quote: "You cannot use the UIControl class directly to instantiate controls."
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Ralph Right, because it doesn't include any kind of UI for any kind of control, but that's not what your question said. This is programmatically how you do the same thing as you're doing with Interface Builder. If you're just using it as a UIView that catches touch events, it's fine. However, you're probably better off adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your view rather than creating an empty `UIControl` either in IB or in code.

Answer (score 0):

> I created xib file. then new Objective c class file inherits from
>   UIView. i set xib class  Objective c class, in interface builder and
>   then change super class of Objective c class to UIControl.